# Изменение mtime с правами доступа группы

Tags: linux, acl

Есть файлы с доступом на запись, выданным с помощью юниксовой группы:

```
$ sudo touch test1
$ sudo chown root:work test1
$ sudo chmod 770 test1
$ ls -lh test1
-rwxrwx--- 1 root work 0 апр 23 19:10 test1
$ whoami
andreymal
$ groups
andreymal adm sudo work
```

Но линукс всё равно не даёт изменять mtime таких файлов:

```
$ touch -t 197001010000.00 test1
touch: установка временных отметок 'test1': Операция не позволена
```

[Я знаю, что это фича](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=utime&category=2&russian=2#lbAD), но не найдётся ли возможность всё-таки выдать доступ на изменение mtime без изменения владельца файлов, без становления рутом и без выдачи пользователю лишних опасных прав?

Comment: А с расширенными правами тоже не прокатит? mount -o acl которые

Comment: @eri может и прокатит, но я в них пока что не очень умею)

Comment: @andreymal https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/access_control_list, https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) - проще говоря, getfacl/setfacl

Comment: @0-LevelUNIXMonk это-то я знаю, но не уверен, что "в лоб" оно возьмёт и заработает (хотя перед отправкой вопроса почему-то поленился взять и попробовать)

Comment: например, в sudoers можно разрешить пользователю беспарольно вызывать (от имени root-а) что-нибудь вроде `/usr/local/bin/touch.mtime`, который представляет собой, например, скрипт оболочки, проверяющий переданные параметры и выполняющий вызов *touch*.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin не очень годится, потому что менять mtime может любая работающая с файлом/каталогом программа (cp, rsync, unzip и т. д.)

Comment: @andreymal а стики биты всякие? прибить права файлов к каталогу.

с setfacl идея то пусть владелец меняется, а эффективные права останутся те же..